# How to connect EVB- ADC7606BSTZ to MCU (STM32)?

Tags: stm32, adc, spi, protocol

I try to connect the EVAL-7606BSTZ to my application, my MCU -

user guide for EVAL:https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/EVAL-AD7605-4SDZ_7606SDZ_7606-6SDZ_7606-4SDZ_7607SDZ_7608SDZ.pdf

I have in my MCU, SPI block, but I'm not sure how to connect the ADC to STM32 , it's not a standard SPI protocol(in the side of the ADC), there are signals like ~CS and SCLK, and that's all, but how to interface with the ADC? this is just reading ?
this is the schematic of the EVAL
[image]

and this is the datasheet of the IC:https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad7606_7606-6_7606-4.pdf

you can see from the datasheet this connection :
[image]

I will ask again, this is just reading? how to configure the relevant register to it?

Comment: I think it's not quite clear what you're asking. If you want to hook it up to a STM32 you'll need to configure it as a SPI device and read just like you would from any other SPI device. See pg. 27 in the datasheet. It says which pins must be tied to which level to enable the SPI protocol.

Comment: Make sure you drive the signal lines at the correct voltage level